# jQuery: loading an entire page to a jQuery object and using it?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I have a page which basically loads using ajax, but I want to switch sevrel elements of it, most notably - the `<title>` tag without sending sevrel XHR requests, so I want to load an entire page to a jQuery object, and use it's elements, so:

something along the line:

```
href = 'http://my-url.com/my-page.php';
dom = $();
dom.load(href);
text = dom.children("title").text();
```

I'm fiddling with this quite a while, and no success,
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$.get(href, function(source) {
    var html = $(source);

    html.find('title').text()
});
```

Comment: This one does fetches it well but it still doesn't give me the title for some reason (it does give me the other elements).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
var href = 'http://localurl.com/my-page.php';
var html = $("html");
//do whatever with html;
```

? It will take entire html into `html` and you can do whatever you want with it